# route names inside a group prefix does not include the prefix

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-routing, laravel-6, laravel-resource

I have these routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin'], 'prefix' => 'admin'], function()
{
    Route::resource(__('route.events'), 'Auth\RoleAdmin\EventController');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:user'], 'prefix' => 'user'], function()
{
    Route::resource(__('route.events'), 'Auth\RoleUser\EventController');
});
```

I would expect the name of the resources routes start with `admin.` and `user.` respectively, but it does not happen.

This is the result of the command `php artisan route:list`:

```
|        | GET|HEAD      | auth/admin/events                                           | events.index                            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RoleAdmin\EventController@index                        | web,auth,role
:admin,guest,role:admin|user                        |
|        | POST          | auth/admin/events                                           | events.store                            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RoleAdmin\EventController@store                        | web,auth,role
:admin,guest,role:admin|user                        |
|        | GET|HEAD      | auth/admin/events/create                                    | events.create                           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RoleAdmin\EventController@create                       | web,auth,role
:admin,guest,role:admin|user                        |
|        | DELETE        | auth/admin/events/{events}                                  | events.destroy                          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RoleAdmin\EventController@destroy                      | web,auth,role
:admin,guest,role:admin|user                        |
|        | GET|HEAD      | auth/admin/events/{events}                                  | events.show                             | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RoleAdmin\EventController@show                         | web,auth,role
:admin,guest,role:admin|user                        |
|        | PUT|PATCH     | auth/admin/events/{events}                                  | events.update                           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RoleAdmin\EventController@update                       | web,auth,role
:admin,guest,role:admin|user                        |
|        | GET|HEAD      | auth/admin/events/{events}/edit                             | events.edit                             | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RoleAdmin\EventController@edit                         | web,auth,role
:admin,guest,role:admin|user                        |
```

As you can see the routes of admin and routes of users have the same names, and the names don't include the prefix.

Comment: "_I would expect the name of the resources routes start with admin. and user. respectively_" `prefix()` prefixes the URL, not the name of route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kerbholz's solution is not working, but it helped me to solve.

```
Route::prefix('admin')
    ->middleware('role:admin')
    ->name('admin.') // <-- I had to add this line in order to work
    ->group(function() {
        Route::resource(__('route.events'), 'Auth\RoleAdmin\EventController');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your routes to have prefix and middleware outside of the group:

```
Route::prefix('admin')
->middleware('role:admin')
->group(function() {
    Route::resource(__('route.events'), 'Auth\RoleAdmin\EventController');
});

Route::prefix('user')
->middleware('role:user')
->group(function() {
    Route::resource(__('route.events'), 'Auth\RoleUser\EventController');
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#route-groups

Comment: @TimLewis: fixed the faulty `prefix->('user')`, thanks

Comment: it seems I get the same result. I get the error "route admin.events.update not defined"

Comment: As I said in my comment on your question: "_prefix() prefixes the URL, not the name of route_"

Comment: I thought laravel did it automatically